# SQL Server 2008 intellisense not working

Tags: sql-server-2008

Am not sure which site this is supposed to be posted on, but after installing SSMS Tools, my intellisense is no longer working.  Please see this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816861/sql-server-2008-intellisense-no-longer-working

Comment: What version are we working with here?

Comment: Since you answered your question on SO you could do the same here to clear this one out from 'unanswered'.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to repair the installation from the DVD and now I have intellisense back.